# After ArrayList.add() in a loop, all elements are identical. Why?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

If I do this [quasi-java-code]:

```
while (loop)
{
    localObject = getDataForObject();
    globalPublicStaticArrayList<Object>.add(localObject);
}
```

All the elements in globalPublicStaticArrayList are identical, equal to the last copy of localObject added. I stepped thru the loop in the debugger and saw that as soon as an Object is added, it is copied in to all the elements of the globalPublicStaticArrayList.

The workaround I found is:

```
while (loop)
{
    localObject = getDataForObject();
    globalPublicStaticArrayList<Object>.add(new Object(localObject.member1, localObject.member2,...));
}
```

Has it something to do with pass-by-reference in Java? How come the elements are identical in the first case? Thanks.

Comment: show the code for `getDataForObject()`. or perhaps your full activity code

Comment: This question was asked before the other question. How is this a duplicate and not that one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java uses call by value, but here those values are *references* to objects.

What you are adding to the list is not a copy of the object, but a copy of the reference. Your method returned the same object each time you called it. It probably should return a new object each time, then you wouldn't need this workaround.

Comment: thanks for your insight. If you are referring to getDataForObject(), it is just a place holder in the question.  I can see in the debugger/log that localObject holds different data for each iteration. The only difference is in the add() call. This is java.util.ArrayList.add();

Comment: @iceman: `I can see in the debugger/log that localObject holds different data for each iteration.` That tells you nothing. It can contain different data but still be the same object. Analogy: Your house can contain different furniture each day, but it's still the same house. Changing the furniture does not make it a different house.

Comment: Ok. I get you. My question now is, after each pass, or rather after each add() call, all elements in globalPublicStaticArrayList become the same? It's like this:

Pass 1:
localObject = 1
globalPublicStaticArrayList = [1];

Pass 2:
localObject = 2
globalPublicStaticArrayList = [2, 2];

Pass 3:
localObject = 3
globalPublicStaticArrayList = [3, 3, 3];

Pass 4:
localObject = someValue
globalPublicStaticArrayList = [ someValue, someValue, someValue, someValue];

Pass N:
localObject = finalValue
globalPublicStaticArrayList = [ finalValue * N times];

Comment: @iceman: You have many references to **the same object** in your list. To create a new object use the `new` operator. Like this: `localObject = new ....;`.

Comment: Got it. Instead of ArrayList<Objects>, I get ArrayList<Pointers to Objects>. Thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 2):

```
globalPublicStaticArrayList<Object>.add(localObject);
```

here you are passing the localObject reference. You you want a copy of every objects you should create a new object at every iteration

Answer (score 0):

In getDataForObject() may be you are not creating "new" object of return type.
Because of that all objects are pointing to same address.